# Ruby Watir -- Trying to loop through links in cnn.com and click each one of them

Tags: ruby, automation, watir

I have created this method to loop through the links in a certain div in the web site. My porpose of the method Is to collect the links insert them in an array then click each one of them.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir-webdriver/wait'

site = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
url = "http://www.cnn.com/"
site.goto url

  box = Array.new
  container = site.div(class: "column zn__column--idx-1")
  wanted_links = container.links


  box << wanted_links
  wanted_links.each do |link|
    link.click
    site.goto url
    site.div(id: "nav__plain-header").wait_until_present
  end

site.close
```

So far it seems like I am only able to click on the first link then I get an error message stating this:

```
  unable to locate element, using {:element=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x634e0a5400fdfade id="0.06177683611003881-3">} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

I am very new to ruby. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that once you navigate to another page, all of the element references (ie those in `wanted_links`) become stale. Even if you return to the same page, Watir/Selenium does not know it is the same page and does not know where the stored elements are.

If you are going to navigate away, you need to collect all of the data you need first. In this case, you just need the `href` values.

```
# Collect the href of each link
wanted_links = container.links.map(&:href)

# You have each page URL, so you can navigate directly without returning to the homepage
wanted_links.each do |link|
  site.goto url
end
```

In the event that the links do not directly navigate to a page (eg they execute JavaScript when clicked), you will need to collect enough data to re-locate the elements later. What you use as the locator will depend on what is known to be static/unique. As an example, I will assume that the link text is a good locator.

```
# Collect the text of each link
wanted_links = container.links.map(&:text)

# Iterate through the links
wanted_links.each do |link_text|
  container = site.div(class: "column zn__column--idx-1")
  container.link(text: link_text).click

  site.back
end
```

Comment: That was great. Thank you for the info @Justin Ko

Comment: Hey Justin I tried this method as well, but I am still getting an error saying "undefined method `click'".   Here is the method in the next comment. Thank you

Comment: 'require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir-webdriver/wait'

site = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
url = "http://www.cnn.com/"
site.goto url

  container = site.div(class: "column zn__column--idx-1")
  wanted_links = container.links.collect(&:text)

  puts wanted_links

  wanted_links[1].click'

Comment: You get that error because you are trying to call `click` on a String (of the link text) rather than a Watir::Anchor element. What are you trying to achieve (as the code you just provided seems quite different than the original code and answer)?

Comment: I was thinking I can get all the links stored in the wanted links. Then I can click on each one and go back to the main page. Example wanted_links[1].click then site.back and again wanted_links[2].click and so on.

Comment: Hopefully I am making sense. Thank you

Comment: The links do not appear to do anything special, so I'm not sure why you want to click each link as opposed to directly navigating to where each link goes. At any rate, I added a second example for where you want to go back to the main page to click the link element.

Comment: Justin Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help