# Loop in table with Watir

Tags: watir

Stuck with watir trying to create a loop to click in all the links included in a table. Currently the table has this format:

```
<table id="test">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td><a href="http://facebook.com">http://facebook.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And my current attempt looks like:

```
browser.table(:id => "test").rows do |tr|
  tr.each do |td|
    td.links.click
  end
end
```

This code above does nothing in the browser & neither returns something in the terminal (no errors, no outputs).

Also tried a different approach using columns:

```
columns = browser.table(:id => "test").strings.transpose

browser.columns.each do |t|
  t.click
  browser.back
end
```

That outputs this error: jsfiddle.rb:24:in `<main>': undefined method`columns' for # (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work to click on each link in the table:

```
my_table = browser.table(:id, 'test')
table_links = my_table.links.map(&:text)
table_links.each do |link_text|
  my_table.link(:text, link_text).click
  browser.back
end
```

Largely based on Justin Ko's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38924388/1250190).

Answer (score 1):

The newer versions of Watir, [version 6.0](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/CHANGES.md#600beta5-2016-09-25), automatically attempts to relocate stale elements. As a result, as long as the initial page does not change each time you reload it, you no longer need to save some sort of reference data before clicking the links.

It simply becomes:

```
my_table = browser.table(:id, 'test')
my_table.links.each do |link|
  link.click
  browser.back
end
```

Comment: Good to know for when I switch over to the new Watir, Justin. I tried that when formulating my answer, but it did not work with Watir-Webdriver 0.9.3.

Comment: Thanks also for the "version 6.0" link you just added. I see that Watir is now out of Beta. I was waiting for that, and I'll be making the jump soon.